# XSLT for Word Documents

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a project where I need to send users Word-documents that are generated from a Linux script. The Word-documents are stored as docx, and will have some markers inside them (ie `${Firstname}`) that will be replaced by the script.

I cannot use Word on this Linux machine. I can only use xsltproc which uses XSLT1.0, which makes grouping much harder.

The script that I have written works fine for most Word-documents, but in some cases Word spreads out a single sentence, or even a word, across multiple `<w:t>` tags when there is no change in styling.

Because of this I'm trying to figure out a way to merge consecutive `<w:t>` tags inside a run (`<w:r>`) if the styling is exactly the same.

Here is some sample input, that, based on the comments below, I have sanitised a bit, but I'm not trying to hide that this is Word-generated XML.

```xml
 <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>{if}${Dossier.Person.City.city}==”New York”{then}HOMECITY!{else}Far away{</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>endif</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>}</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr>
      <w:pgSz/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="708"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

- Remove all `<w:proofErr />` elements. This I can do easily with my XSLT.

But then, I would basically like to do:

- iterate over all `<w:p>` elements
- if they contain consecutive runs (`<w:r>`) where the styling is exactly the same (`<w:rPr>`) then just create one run, with the styling once, and merge all the text (`<w:t>`).
- keep everything else in the XML

So my desired end result in this case would be:

```xml
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>{if}${Dossier.Person.City.city}==”New York”{then}HOMECITY!{else}Far Away{endif}</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr>
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="708"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
```

I have come this far, but I don't know how to check for those exact values inside the `<w:rPr>`, which means the style changes inside a paragraph have now disappeared. It now just picks up the first `<w:rPr>` node.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Ignore w:proofErr nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="w:proofErr" />

    <!-- w:r nodes are processed in the for-each loop -->
    <xsl:template match="w:r"/>

    <xsl:template match="w:p">
      <xsl:element name="w:p">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="w:r">
          <xsl:copy-of select="w:r[1]/w:rPr"/> 
          <xsl:element name="w:t">
            <xsl:for-each select="w:r">
              <xsl:for-each select="w:t">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had tried to figure out various ways of de-duplication before I posted, but based on the kind comments I have looked again into Muenchian grouping. I still don't understand how I could use this here.

I don't care if multiple `<w:rPr>` have the exact same value within a paragraph, as long as there are `<w:rPr>` between them that have a different value.

Comment: Your "question" reads like a specification for work to be done.  That is inappropriate here. 
 Read [ask], then attempt it yourself, post your code as part of a [mcve], and explain exactly how what you're getting isn't matching what you want.

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: It's also likely an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215), because to do search-and-replace for OOXML, eliminating consecutive runs with identical formatting does not really solve the problem.  Users expect search and replace to work independent of formatting transitions.  OP should do background reading in the area, starting with [ooxml search replace](https://www.google.com/search?q=ooxml+search+replace&oq=ooxml+search+replace)

Comment: I'm sorry, I will rephrase the question, I did not intend to make it a 'have somebody else do my work' part, I figured explaining all would help with answering.

Comment: Regarding the XY problem, I have an underlying issue where I want to replace strings inside a Word XML (the 'X' in the XY). I noticed that (especially Word for Mac) sometimes generates horrible XML that makes this problem harder. I cannot use the Word search & replace functions in scripting tools on Linux servers in an easy way. So I figured I would try to find a way to fix the Word XML (the 'Y' in the XY). There is another Y, but it does not work always: https://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=3072 and it does not work on a Mac. So I think cleaning up the Word-XM makes most sense.

Comment: Regarding the ooxml search replace, I did find that document before. But since I'll only be replacing tags that users have put in (ie `${Something}`) there should not be instances where a single keyword is split across multiple runs. BUT, some word versions sometimes split them across multiple runs, even when the formatting is exactly the same.

Comment: Merging consecutive runs of sibling nodes that share a common value is easy in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:for-each-group` with the `group-adjacent` attribute. If you're limited to XSLT 1.0 then it gets more complex. Several methods have been proposed - here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262200/3016153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Ignore w:proofErr nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="w:proofErr" />
  
  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="w:r">
    <xsl:variable name="w:rPr" select="w:rPr"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="w:rPr"/> 
      <xsl:element name="w:t">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(w:t|following-sibling::w:r[w:rPr=$w:rPr]/w:t)/node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w:r[not(w:rPr=$w:rPr)][1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but https://pastebin.com/AMhaZJa0 still merges runs that have a change inside the `<w:rPr>` tag and results in https://pastebin.com/TSJy5pWQ

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I did not understand it should only merge w:r if the w:rPr are the same. I have adjusted the xsl- example.
You should adjust the XML-example to make that clear.